# Unable to run PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 12 Canonical Cloud Image

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cloud, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

I use Vagrant 1.5 with standard Vagrantfile and [Canonical Ubuntu 12 Box](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/20140519/precise-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box)
Then I log in to VM with `vagrant ssh` and execute this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib python-psycopg2 -y
sudo -u postgres psql
```

And get such error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This is very strange, this steps are described in [official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).
What is the problem it might be?

### UPDATE

Postgres process is not running right after install, I checked it with `ps -ef | grep postgr` command. `sudo service postgresql status` returns nothing. That is the full log of packegs installation: https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/2292aa9a53154217ff39

There is some interesting lines:

```
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

pg_createcluster 9.1 main --start
```

And after I try to execute this command I get:

```
$  pg_createcluster 9.1 main --start
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
```

So this is locale issue. What I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en -y
```

Not helped. And:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

Was failed with:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MESSAGES = "POSIX",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Comment: Well, is it running? Where are the logs from your apt install? Where are the server logs showing it running? How do you expect people to provide help without even the bare minimum of information?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Your remark actually led me to what is real cause of the problem - looking closely to installation log was uncovered some useful details

Comment: Very odd. I've never seen two locales mixed up like that. Still, that's why the logs are there, otherwise you could have spent days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was resolved this issue by running this lines:

```
echo "echo $'LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8\n' > /etc/default/locale" | sudo -s;
echo "echo $'LANG=en_US.UTF-8\n' >> /etc/default/locale" | sudo -s;
echo "echo $'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\n' >> /etc/default/locale" | sudo -s;
echo "echo $'LC_MESSAGES=POSIX\n' >> /etc/default/locale" | sudo -s;
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8;
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales;
```